# ReactJS - Avoid resetting state when updating an object within state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching some data from the server to populate a list of items, and each item got a onClick event binded to the items id, that changes the UI to be disabled when clicked.

**My problem** is that the UI changes to disabled perfectly on the first click, but when I go on to click on the next item it resets the first one, so there is only one button disabled at a time. How do I make it so I can disable all the items I want, without resetting the previous state?

```
  class Video extends Component {
     constructor () {
     super()
      this.state = {
     isDisabled: false
 }
}


handleClick(frag, voted, event){
 event.preventDefault()

 this.setState({
   isDisabled: {
      [frag]: true
   }
 })
}
```

**Snippet of what I return in the UI that changes the disabled button**

```
<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, frags.id, frags.voted)} disabled={this.state.isDisabled[frags.id]} className="rating-heart-2">
     <i className="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </button>
```

I would really appreciate all tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are completely replacing `isDisabled` each time you update state, but you really just want to add a new property to it.  Try the following:

```
handleClick(frag, voted, event){
 event.preventDefault();
 let {isDisabled} = this.state;
 isDisabled[frag] = true;

 this.setState({isDisabled});
}
```

Comment: Or if you're using experimental features from ES6 you could use object spread to copy all properties: `this.setState({ isDisabled: { ...this.state.isDisabled, [frag]: true } })`

Comment: That is true.  Another ES6 way one may prefer would be to use `this.setState({isDisabled: Object.assign(isDisabled, {frag: true})}`.